# How do I print text along with a calculated value in R

Tags: r

At the end of the following code I want to print `n_species`, but I first want to print "The number of species is" and then the value. How can I do this?

```
n_species <- 0
n_invisibility <- 0
for(i in Species) {
    n_species <- n_species + 1

    for(i in Invisibility){
        if(i == "Y") {
            n_invisibility <- n_invisibility + 1
        }
        else {
            n_invisibility <- n_invisibility + 0
        }
    }
}
print(n_species)
print(n_invisibility)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that allows to easily control formatting of numbers:

```
sprintf("The number of species is %i.", n_species)
```

Comment: you can use `cat` too

Answer (score 1):

`print(paste("The number of species is",n_species))`

Paste also takes the parameters sep, where the default is `sep=" "`, and collapse, which is basically separation for vectors, if you're trying to print one as a string (and more).

Comment: Depending on where it's being used, `paste()` alone -- instead of `print(paste())` -- might do the trick.

Comment: also, you can `cat` instead of `print` to avoid the `[1]`

Comment: You can use `message` as well.